# Recurring "No Ledger found" error by endorser

Tags: ledger, endorser

I am trying to bake solo on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS both on notebook and in Windows VMware Workstation.

Everything is up to date - Tezos node, Ledger Nano S firmware, Tezos Baking app installed by LedgerLive.

I have this recurring "No Ledger found" error by tezos-endorser-003-PsddFKi3 both on Ubuntu & VMWare Ubuntu :

```
Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###'

Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###'

Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###'



Mar ## - client.scheduling: Error while baking:

Mar ## - client.scheduling: Error:

Mar ## - client.scheduling:   No Ledger found for abc-def-ghi-jkl/ed25519

Mar ## - client.scheduling:


Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###'

Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###'
```

How can I fix this, please?

Comment: are you seeing this error both in Ubuntu and in Windows ? also does the tezos-client recognize your ledger ?

Comment: yes and yes. ( I am sorry for not prompt answer. )

Comment: We've done a check for ledger compatibility with Ubuntu 18.04 with Tezos Baking v2.0.0 and things seem to be working fine. Confirming it is only the endorser having issues and not the baker? Other communications with the ledger work fine, like `tezos-client list connected ledgers`? If only the endorser is having issues, have you double checked you used the right alias?

Comment: According to tzscan.io - yes it is only endorser having issues, baker/baking is fine. `tezos-client list connected ledgers` recognizes my ledger. Alias I used is the correct one. When the error occurs its message " No Ledger found for abc-def-ghi-jkl/ed25519" lists the ledger for the alias "ledger" with which output for successful endorsement is printed -->> Mar ## - client.endorsement: Injected endorsement for block '##' (level 3#, contract ledger) '###' @mikereinhart

Comment: @tzUserABC thanks for the additional information! If I'm reading your recent comment correctly, your endorser is only failing *sometimes*, not all the time. Is that right? The ledger can only sign one thing at a time. I see this error when the ledger is already signing something else, like a block. This can be very common if the node is catching up and the ledger signs a string of queued blocks, preventing the endorser from finding the busy ledger device

Comment: @mikereinhart thank you for digging in! Yes endorser fails _sometimes_ , not all the time. Let me measure / test  things again in  mainnet bed  on Ubuntu notebook. I will report to you ASAP. No, - the node looks like is being updated without catching up, but who knows. TY. Yet according tzscan.io  no blocks missed, only endorsements. // staying  in touch

Comment: Sounds great @tzUserABC - I also recommend setting up debug logs - https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos#display-debug-logs. This will print the bytes being sent to and from the ledger during an operation, and can be very helpful when debugging issues

Comment: Did you end up having any luck here?

Comment: @tzUserABC could you please post an answer to your question if you ended up solving it one way or another ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are there any other commands polling the ledger at the time of baking/endorsement? For example if you run

```
tezos-client list connected ledgers
```

this will block the communication and could cause the baking/endorsement to fail.

If you want to **double check the communication** between tezos client and  ledger without waiting for an endorsement or baking, just set the watermark (HWM) to the current block height:

```
tezos-client set ledger high watermark for "ledger://your-address" to <level>
```